# select order by - heading of items in group

Tags: php, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a table "items" with musical pieces, headers like "title" "composer" "description".. various pieces per composer.. trying to get a PHP script to `SELECT * from items, order by "composer"` but generate a header in the `while` for the composer, then output all rows with their work, and so on for the next.. i.e.:

**ITEMS TABLE**

```
-------------------------------
David Drury   | piece 1  | info
-------------------------------
David Drury   | piece 2  | info
--------------------------------
Alfonzo Smith | piece 1  | info
--------------------------------
David Drury   | piece 3  | info
```

### Output

David Drury

- piece 1  | info
- piece 2 | info
- piece 3 | info

Alfonzo Smith

- piece 1 | info

Can I do this from one table? or might I be able to create a table for composers with a join that can see the composer, output the header, then outport the pieces from the join in the items table?

Comment: You can do this in one table.

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY column_name ASC`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.. Subquery. For anyone whom this might help, this is what I've used:

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT Composer FROM items"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
$Composer = $row["Composer"];
echo '<h2>'.$row["Composer"].'</h2>';
$sqlCommand2 = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE Composer = '$Composer'"; 
$query2 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlCommand2) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) { 
    $idPart = $row2["idPart"];
    $Composer = $row2["Composer"];
    $Title = $row2["Title"];
    $Opus = $row2["Opus"];
    $Instrumentation = $row2["Instrumentation"];
    $Type = $row2["Type"];
    $ISMN = $row2["ISMN"];
    $RRP = $row2["RRP"];
    $information = $row2["information"];



    echo '<h5>'.$Title.' - '.$information.'</h5>';
}
            }
```